# Openstack instance neutron issue

Tags: openstack-neutron, kolla-ansible

I have deployed Multinode cluster of Openstack through kolla-ansible zed release. The problem I am facing is instances created cannot pick any Ip addresses (Rather than loop back ip or ipv6 addresses) from the created tenant networks with the default network type is vxlan. However, if I can assign ip manually to the eth0 interface in cirros instance, the interface is up with the ip address, but still, it can’t able to ping even its router gateway. Router can’t be able to ping instance ip address but only ping itself as verified below:

The following troubleshooting steps, I have followed and concluded:

- The Tenant network is created and its port: network: router_interface, network:dhcp, compute:nova are in admin up and active state.
- The router interfaces are in up state and in complete nova zone.
- The instance is running and active state and automatically pick ip address from the created tenant network as displayed in gui but inside the vm it can’t pick any ip address.
- The security groups have been defined to allow icmp, tcp, udp for inbound/outbound traffic.

Hence, I may not be able to ping and ssh instance from the controller node further these instances won’t be able to connect to the internet until the issue get resolved.

Can you guide me how to resolve these issues related to network connectivity so I may able to send you the required files to troubleshoot easily?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use VMware or a different virtualization technology? I experienced same problem with VMware on our Test environment but If i set manual ip address it is worked for me. My problem; DHCP(DORA) packets doesn't send between network interfaces. When I check with tcpdump. I just see Discover or Offer packets. I couldn't see request or ack packet. We cant fix this issue and We started use bare-metal server for test environment such as production. Everything is fine now.

Comment: Yes, The Openstack is deployed on the top of VMware Esxi.

Comment: On bare metal servers which hypervisor you have choose to deploy cloud? as of my case,  the Openstack is deployed on the top of VMware Esxi.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @ASM-12 We are not using any hypervisor. We are using Ubuntu 20.04 directly.